# Firebase java object serialization and Inheritance

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does it also serialize inherited properties?

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Item extend BaseObservable {
    private String foo;

    public Item() { }

    @Bindable
    public String getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've put it an internal bug to see if we can make the annotations work with inheritance. Until then, Andrew has the right idea.

Comment: You reported a bug with firebase? Link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue and found your question. While I could not find a definitive answer elsewhere, some experimentation revealed that neither `public` fields nor getters are inherited.

Since my base class is abstract, I just made the fields protected and implemented getters to return them in each subclass. The repetition isn't ideal, but my objects are now saving in Firebase with the inherited fields.

Comment: Good find! I didn't realize that workaround.