# FATAL EXCEPTION: main com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to parse to snapshot at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValueInternal

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been working on an android app for attendance with localization. The database is connected to firebase to track users in realtime. While implementing the registration form I've been through this Error and I could never get out of it. Whenever I try to register as a student or a teacher the application crashes . I referenced that [very close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822853/firebase-setvalue-not-working-on-android-failed-to-parse-to-snapshot) but it didn't help me also.
here is my code

```
package com.example.appla.iattended;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;


public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText email, password,id, confirmPassword;
    String str_email, str_password,str_id, str_confirmPassword;
    Boolean email_verified, password_verified, isTA, id_verified;
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://yattend-755ad.firebaseio.com/");

    Button signUp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        email = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.txt_signup_email);
        password = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.txt_signup_password);
        confirmPassword = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.txt_signup_confirm_password);
        id = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.txt_signup_id);
        email.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus)
                    email.setHint("");
                else
                    email.setHint("GUC email");
            }
        });
        password.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus)
                    password.setHint("");
                else
                    password.setHint("Password");
            }
        });
        confirmPassword.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus)
                    confirmPassword.setHint("");
                else
                    confirmPassword.setHint("Confirm Password");
            }
        });
        id.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus)
                    id.setHint("");
                else
                    id.setHint("XX-XXXXX");
            }
        });
        signUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //generate strings
                str_email = email.getText().toString();
                str_password = password.getText().toString();
                str_confirmPassword = confirmPassword.getText().toString();
                str_id = id.getText().toString();

               //checking password
                if(str_password.equals(str_confirmPassword)){

                    password_verified = true;
                }else{
                    password_verified = false;
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,
                            "Passwords do not match, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                //checking email
                if(str_email.endsWith("@student.guc.edu.eg")){
                    email_verified = true;
                    isTA =false;
                }else if(str_email.endsWith("@guc.edu.eg")) {
                    email_verified = true;
                    isTA=true;

                }else{
                    email_verified = false;
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,
                        "Incorrect Email. Please use your GUC email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                //checking id
                if(str_id.contains("-") && str_id.length() > 4){
                    id_verified =true;
                }else if (str_id.equals("") && isTA) {
                    id_verified = true;
                } else{
                        id_verified =false;
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this,
                            "Please insert GUC ID or if TA, leave blank.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                //To firebase
                if(email_verified && password_verified && id_verified){
                    //Insert
                    User user = new User(str_email,str_password,str_id,isTA);
                    Firebase newRef = ref.child("Users").push();
                    newRef.setValue(user);
                    if(isTA){
                        //Redirect to TA's page
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, StartSessionActivity.class);
                        SignUpActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                    }else{
                        //Redirect to students page
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, StudentActivity.class);
                        SignUpActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                }

            }
        });


    }
}
```

here is User class:

```
package com.example.appla.iattended;


public class User {
     String email, password,id;
     Boolean isTa;

    public User(String email, String password, String id,Boolean isTa){
        this.email=email;
        this.password=password;
        this.id=id;
        this.isTa=isTa;
    }
}
```

and here is my generated Log whenever I press the button register

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to parse to snapshot
                                                                               at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValueInternal(Firebase.java:347)
                                                                               at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValue(Firebase.java:238)
                                                                               at com.example.appla.iattended.SignUpActivity$5.onClick(SignUpActivity.java:122)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No serializer found for class com.example.appla.iattended.User and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
                                                                               at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2615)
                                                                               at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:2542)
                                                                               at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValueInternal(Firebase.java:336)
                                                                               at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValue(Firebase.java:238) 
                                                                               at com.example.appla.iattended.SignUpActivity$5.onClick(SignUpActivity.java:122) 
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211) 
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773) 
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                            Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class com.example.appla.iattended.User and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
                                                                               at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:59)
                                                                               at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:26)
                                                                               at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:118)
                                                                               at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:2593)
                                                                               at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:2542) 
                                                                               at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValueInternal(Firebase.java:336) 
                                                                               at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setValue(Firebase.java:238) 
                                                                               at com.example.appla.iattended.SignUpActivity$5.onClick(SignUpActivity.java:122) 
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211) 
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773) 
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to include your `User` class?

Comment: @LewisMcGeary done!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about this, as it seems from your error messages that you're using a legacy version of Firebase. So first I'd suggest if that's the case, looking at the [migration instructions](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android).

The current version of Firebase [shows an expected structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write) for classes you use to read and write to the database as follows:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class User {

    public String username;
    public String email;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public User(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure how this translates to older versions but you may wish to try including the empty constructor and making your fields public.

Answer (score 0):

> no properties discovered  ... EMPTY_BEAN

Your fields are package-private and you have no getters.

Add some getters or make the fields public.

---

You also need to add an empty constructor if you plan on using `getValue(User.class)`