# Firebase Database: object inheritance not supported?

Tags: android, inheritance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I upgraded to [Firebase 9.0.2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app). When saving to the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) I cannot get objects to map like they used to in older versions. See my [sample project demonstrating this](https://github.com/Binghammer/firebase_inheritance).

For instance, take these objects:

```
public class Vehicle {

    private String vin;
    private int wheels;
    private int color;
    private double price;
    private String type;

    public Vehicle() { }

    ....
    //public accessors
    .... 
}
```

and

```
public class Truck extends Vehicle {

    private int bedLength;
    private boolean fourWheelDrive;
    private boolean diesel;

    public Truck() { }

    ....
    //public accessors
    .... 
}
```

If I were to create and save a `Truck` object:

```
final Truck truck = new Truck();
truck.setVin(getRef().push().getKey());
truck.setVehicleType("truck");
truck.setColor(random.color());
truck.setPrice(random.price());
truck.setBedLength(random.number(8));
truck.setDiesel(random.bool());
truck.setFourWheelDrive(random.bool());
truck.setVehicleType(VehicleType.TRUCK);

FirebaseDatabase
     .getInstance()
     .getReference()
     .child(vehicle.getVin())
     .setValue(truck);
```

I only see values from `Truck`, and none from `Vehicle`:

```
"-KKpeYZO4eG3lAYyCd40" : {
    "bedLength" : 1,
    "diesel" : true,
    "fourWheelDrive" : true
}
```

I am considering making a JSON mapper and manually map all of my objects every time I save or retrieve(Like older versions of Firebase used to do). If there are better solutions or plans to fix this I would really like to know before I start down that rabbit hole.

In the meantime, I have followed the advice [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37370148/1642079), which that makes for ugly, redundant, and bug-prone code.

---

### Edit:

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37548330/1642079) from Firebase engineer, [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) did not work for me because I believe that it is geared towards *deserializing* objects, where I am struggling with *serializing*.

Comment: See Kato's comment at this [related question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37331293/firebase-java-object-serialization-and-inheritance).

Comment: Yeah, I have seen that question. It was no help because there is no solution.